# facebook feed with revolution slider does not work : failed to load stream

Tags: wordpress, stream, revolution-slider

I got an error while using the facebook feed from slider revolution. It  works perfectly when I use it in local but when I launch it in normal url, I got this error : `Revolution Slider Error: Failed to load Stream`.

Do I have to change something in my .htaccess ou php.ini maybe ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by either:

- A problem with your API credentials or
- your hosting provider has disabled stream wrappers

Check your error logs for a message like this:

`PHP Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.facebook.com[…]): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found`

If you find messages like this, you should contact your hosting provider to enable stream wrappers in the php.ini file.

Ref: https://www.themepunch.com/faq/failed-to-open-stream-5-0/

Comment: Did you check that the setting is actually on in your php.ini? I wouldn't just take their word for it :) Also, have you checked your error log for any additional information, and that your API is set up correctly on the live site?

Comment: the setting is actually on ? I do not see the log, when I write `php_flag log_errors on` on my .htaccess I got an error on my website... How do I check my API ? Sorry but that's my first wordpress website.. Thanks

Comment: You need to set up the API in the Slider plugin so you can connect to Facebook. How did you do it on your local site? If you check the link I included in my answer, it has a big screenshot showing where your API settings are.

Comment: Yes, but have you double-checked that it still set up correctly in the plugin on the hosting server? Your hosting provider probably already has error logging turned on, so check the logs in your hosting to see if there are errors in it. You should be able to access them through your control panel or file manager depending on your hosting provider but if you're not sure where they are, your provider will be able to tell you.

Comment: actually log_errors is desactivated by the hosting server and I can not modify it unfortunately ..

Comment: Well that's not very helpful of them! You should be able to turn them on through php.ini. If you are 100% sure your API is set up correctly on the hosted site, then we really need to see the logs to see if we can find out any more about this problem.

Comment: well, I am not 100% sure the API is set correctly but I did the same than on local so I have copy and paste the API and the secret key inside my slider settings. I am trying to get my log_errors working